# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'generate_barcode'

Tags: python, erpnext, frappe

I was trying to retrieve some data from DB in Python.and I got this error:
Traceback:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
File "/home/adminuser/frappe-bench-hitech/apps/frappe/frappe/app.py",    line 49, in application
response = frappe.handler.handle()
File "/home/adminuser/frappe-bench-hitech/apps/frappe/frappe/handler.py",  line 66, in handle
execute_cmd(cmd)
File "/home/adminuser/frappe-bench-hitech/apps/frappe/frappe/handler.py", line 77, in execute_cmd
method = get_attr(cmd)
File "/home/adminuser/frappe-bench-hitech/apps/frappe/frappe/handler.py", line 98, in get_attr
method = frappe.get_attr(cmd)
File "/home/adminuser/frappe-bench- hitech/apps/frappe/frappe/__init__.py", line 519, in get_attr
return getattr(get_module(modulename), methodname)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'generate_barcode'
```

here is what I was doing:

```
 @frappe.whitelist()
def generate_barcode(self):

    brand=self.get("brand_code")

    final_barcode="%05d" % random.randint(0,9999)

    return {'final_barcode':final_barcode,'brand':brand}
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried printing out that `modulename` to check it's indeed the module `generate_barcode` is in?

Comment: @satoru I dont know how to print the modulename.When I tries, it shows error

Comment: Just open `/home/adminuser/frappe-bench- hitech/apps/frappe/frappe/__init__.py` and add a `print`.

Comment: Where are you calling this function from?

Answer (score -1):

The whitespace before `@frappe.whitelist()` could be the problem.

Comment: No, it could not - that would lead to an instant `IndentationError` when loading the module. Don't post speculative answers please; it would have taken 10 seconds in an interactive interpreter to test that before posting.